# Passenger hypoxia in a small plane at 11,000 feet: what is the pilot's responsibility?

Tags: high-altitude, oxygen

An acquaintance of mine visiting western U.S. was recently a guest passenger in a small plane flying from [Santa Fe, New Mexico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Fe,_New_Mexico) to Colorado reaching an altitude of 11,000 feet. She related that she started experiencing [hypoxia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoxia_(medical)) and there wasn't any supplemental oxygen available. Apparently they couldn't reduce altitude (mountains). She said that since then she has had trouble breathing, has gone for medical tests, etc.

I didn't want to be "that guy", so I didn't ask, but it occurred to me to wonder if the pilot was irresponsible in not having supplemental oxygen available. Apparently the pilot and his other passenger were from the area and acclimated to the altitude.

Since one can't just "ask" someone if they will be OK at that altitude, should the plane (pilot) have had oxygen available? In other words, is this an area of pilot responsibility?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is flying at 14,000 MSL safe for children without supplemental oxygen?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/19043/is-flying-at-14-000-msl-safe-for-children-without-supplemental-oxygen)

Comment: The cut-off is 12,500 feet for the requirement of supplemental oxygen, and this one doesn't involve children, so @fooot I don't see why this is a duplicate question?

Comment: @falstro the answers provide good general advice which seems to be the same, consulting a regular doctor rather than a pediatrician, of course.

Comment: So once again we are at the community dilemma of, "should we mark duplicate *answers* rather than only duplicate questions?"  It is certainly related.

Comment: @RyanMortensen that's not a dilemma, that's how SE works. from the help page: `The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.` and the duplicate banner states: `This question already has an answer here: [link to other question]`

Comment: @Federico that question answers a different question, and is unlikely to attract answers that are specific to this question. By closing the question, you're effectively suppressing people from answering this specific question. Just because a different question has an answer that *you* decide apply to this question, doesn't mean there aren't other answers that fit better that are *not* applied to the other question. So yes. It is a dilemma.

Comment: @Federico yes, that is the goal, but there is a condition that requires it to be the same question, and not simply one that will receive related answers.  Learning whether or not 14,000 Ft. is safe for child-passengers doesn't inform me at all of whether the pilot has a duty of care for anyone's oxygen levels at 11,000 Ft.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no regulatory requirement for oxygen to be available for anyone on board an aircraft so long as it remains at altitudes of 12,500' MSL or less. And only the required minimum flight crew is required to have oxygen if they are flying above 12,500' up to and including 14,000 MSL' IF they will be at those altitudes for more than 30 minutes. [CFR 91.211](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?node=14:2.0.1.3.10#se14.2.91_1211)  If they were going above 15,000' MSL that would be another story.
So the short of it is, No, that pilot was not irresponsible, perhaps, maybe slightly inconsiderate, but not irresponsible.

The reason for this is the lower density of the air isn't low enough to harm the majority of passengers.  Except for extreme cases, such as those with severe and uncontrolled asthma or heavy smokers, the worst thing that would happen would be the passengers would just get sleepy and fall asleep.  This is natural, and because the body does not need as much oxygen when asleep.  For passengers there generally won't be any harm done from a mild case altitude induced hypoxic hypoxia.

And YES! You can ask someone if they will be 'OK' at higher altitudes!  Just as it is not only 'OK' but required to ask their weight for weight and balance calculations. (And quite frankly I believe most people find that more intrusive.)
In fact you should take 5 minutes to tell your passengers that the flight will be in excess of, say 11,000', that way they can be prepared for some unusual effects and not have to worry about them.  To take it a step further, remember you are the Pilot in Command and you should be aware of your passenger's limitations as that **may** trigger any self imposed safety limitations you have for the safety of the flight.

Now, if you just want passengers to be comfortable and/or they absolutely insist on not taking a little nap, then it is entirely up to you if you want to carry a portable aviation oxygen canister with you for your passengers.

For further information on hypoxia I would recommend the [FAA's page](https://www.faa.gov/pilots/training/airman_education/topics_of_interest/hypoxia/) on it and the differing effects on pilots, and by extension passengers.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, thanks! It just struck me odd that my friend could find herself in a known, potentially health-threatening situation like that. I don't know all the details or what questions were asked or assurances given. It just seemed odd and (to me) potentially irresponsible that some small tank of O2 was not on board given the flight itinerary. But hey, I'm just a land crab, not a flier 

Comment: In some people, especially at night, hypoxia symptoms can occur at altitudes as low as 5000 feet. Certainly as a pilot if I'm flying above 8000 feet I'd want an O2 meter to determine levels of hypoxia in myself, but passengers are a different story (they aren't flying the plane).

Comment: Classical skiing regions in europe are higher, using the term *health-threatening* is somewhat funny. Maybe she was just sick.

Comment: @Peter when you go skiing, the transition is slow, giving your body time to adapt (more red blood cells I think, which is why many athletes train at higher altitudes before a competition). When you fly you climb in a matter of minutes, it can absolutely be hazardous to your health, hypoxia is not to be taken lightly.

Comment: The transition-time is a point. But waiting for more red blood cells will not work, you need days or even weeks for this type of altitude training.

Comment: @falstro You have to live at altitude for weeks for your body to adapt to it. A slow drive up a mountain isn't nearly enough time to change anything, so a ski resort above 11000 is no different from that flight.

Comment: Glad to help! If I had known you were not a pilot I would have chosen a different word set to describe the different effects of altitude and the medical effects therein. If you need any additional clarification let me know.  Please let your friend know that she was not in any danger and she could have easily talked to her pilot and he/she would have explained it to save her a trip to a doctor!  As a pilot I can say, most every one of us has no problem with answering general questions about a flight like this!

Comment: Even though one can **ask** passengers whether they will be OK with this-or-that altitude, chances are that the passenger who'll have a problem _won't have the faintest idea_ what they can handle if you ask them before departing. So you can ask all you want, you just won't get any wiser from the answer you get. In contrast, if you ask for someone's weight, there a good possibility that they know the correct answer. The two questions are not comparable at all.

Comment: @HenningMakholm  Just to clarify the record, I was comparing the two questions' legitimacy for the pilot to ask, **not** the accuracy of the information.  Also the pilot should not be looking for the passenger to know exactly their personal tolerance, rather to find out if they have severe asthma or are a heavy smoker.  This way the pilot can be more informed and make adjustments in either altitude or to carry Oxygen on a flight when they normally would not.  There's always the **chance** that the passenger could know their limitations and there's no downside to the pilot asking the question.